# Javascript classes and DWR

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, dwr

I've been playing with DWR and converters for a while and I really wanted to map my Java classes to JavaScript classes. Using DWR converters, I have the option to point out what is the name of my JS constructor given a Java class. So far so good... The problem arises when my JS constructor is within a JS package-like name (just like YUI's package system, eg `my.beautiful.package.MyClass`). DWR's current implementation doesn't allow me to use this kind of construct, giving me a `SyntaxError` when I try to use it. Is there an elegant way arround this limitation?

Comment: I don't have a workaround, but for your information there is an opened issue
about this : http://bugs.directwebremoting.org/bugs/browse/DWR-103
If I am wrong and it is not the same problem as what you described, let me know
and I will delete this comment.

Comment: Thats right, I wonder if they will fix it only for version 3. Here we use version 2 yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the this isn't possible directly. I have in my current work project experimented with enhancing each returned object on the client side with methods from a Javascript class, which gets the result that I think you are interested in.

```
DwrService.getThings({
  callback:function(things){
    for(thing in things){
      YAHOO.augmentProto(thing, my.beautiful.package.MyClass);
    }
    // do your stuff here
  }
});
```

I'll have to check at work on monday (now is sunday) that augmentProto is correct one to use, but I think it is. There may even be a better hook into DWR that'll allow you to do this on the fly automagically.

Comment: One thing that I did, I "globalized" all needed constructors used by DWR, (using the notation as follows *my_beautiful_package_MyClass*) although it works, its not that elegant =/